# Generate all subsets of a string using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, subset

`string = 'abc'`. All subsets of said string are: `[a b c ab abc ac bc '(empty string)']`.
I need to generate all of these subsets using a recursive function, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: First do it using ballpen and paper.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: think about subsets of subsets and how that might relate to recursion.

Answer (score 1):

For each char recur to use and not use

```
s = 'abc'

def recur(s, prefix, out):
    if len(s) > 0:
        recur(s[1:], prefix+s[0], out)
        recur(s[1:], prefix, out)
        out.append(prefix+s[0])
    return out

print recur(s, '', [''])
```

outputs

```
['', 'abc', 'ac', 'ab', 'bc', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, you can write it as a one line lambda.

```
lambda s: { s[j:(j+i)] for i in range(len(s)+1) for j in range(len(s)-i+1) }
```