# Create all subsets from string- recursively

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I am trying to create all subset of a given string **recursively**.
Given string = 'aab', we generate all subsets for the characters being distinct.
The answer is: `["", "b", "a", "ab", "ba", "a", "ab", "ba", "aa", "aa", "aab", "aab", "aba", "aba", "baa", "baa"]`.
I have been looking at several solutions  such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318311/generate-all-subsets-of-a-string-using-recursion)
but I am trying to make the function accept a single variable- only the string and work with that, and can't figure out how.
I have been also looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332412/python-recursive-function-to-display-all-subsets-of-given-set) solution of a similar problem, but as it deals with lists and not strings I seem to have some trouble transforming that to accept and generate strings.
Here is my code, in this example I can't connect the str to the list. Hence my question.
**I edited the input and the output.**

```
def gen_all_strings(word):

    if len(word) == 0:
        return ''

    rest = gen_all_strings(word[1:])

    return  rest + [[ + word[0]] + dummy for dummy in rest]
```

Comment: You do not appear to have written *any* code of your own; please post what you have.

Comment: 'aa' and 'bb' are not subsets of 'ab'

Comment: Without recursion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870709/python-every-possible-combination-of-a-string

Comment: What exactly was the problem with the code you have written?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python every possible combination of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870709/python-every-possible-combination-of-a-string)

Comment: @sK500 in this example, they are considered to be distinct characters, as I am trying to create subsets of all words from a string. Each entry counts. Maybe I didn't call it the correct way, rather I should have called it: Permutations with repetition.

Comment: @Anwarvic no, it does not answer to my criteria of a recursive function.

Comment: @NewPythonUser same here, not recursive and not a function.
It's just a solution using python's moduls.

Comment: Shouldn't the subset be: `['', 'a', 'b', 'ab']`?  Why do you have 'aa', 'bb', and both 'ab' and 'ba'?

Comment: @DarrylG yes, let me rename it- 'Permutations with repetition', and I have edited the set and output in the original question,

Comment: why is it required to be recursive?

Comment: @GáborFekete because this is the intention of the exercise, not just for fun :)

Comment: @ScottHunter I have supplied a code now.
Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @NewPythonUser Yes, about recursion.

Comment: Don’t you have a teacher whom you could ask for help?

Comment: @NewPythonUser No man, online courses..

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import *

def recursive_product(s,r=None,i=0):
    if r is None:
        r = []
    if i>len(s):
        return r
    for c in product(s, repeat=i):
        r.append("".join(c))
    return recursive_product(s,r,i+1)

print(recursive_product('ab'))
print(recursive_product('abc'))
```

Output:

`['', 'a', 'b', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']`

`['', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']`

To be honest it feels really forced to use recursion in this case, a much simpler version that has the same results:

```
nonrecursive_product = lambda s: [''.join(c)for i in range(len(s)+1) for c in product(s,repeat=i)]
```

Comment: can you do it without passing on the i and r?
meaning- only passing on the string itself?
I know it's forced...

Comment: @Stan--for avoid passing i & r add a default for r: `def recursive_product(s,r=None,i=0):
  if r is None: r = []`.  So now usage becomes: `print(recursive_product('ab'))`

Answer (score 0):

This is the [powerset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset) of the set of characters in the string.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

s = set('ab') #split string into a set of characters

# combinations gives the elements of the  powerset of a given length r
# from_iterable puts all these into an 'iterable'
# which is converted here to a list

list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1)))
```

Comment: thanks, But I was looking for a solution by defining a recursive function with only one input- the string.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import itertools as it

s='aab'
subsets = sorted(list(map("".join, it.chain.from_iterable(it.permutations(s,r) for r in range(len(s) + 1)))))

print(subsets)
# ['', 'a', 'a', 'aa', 'aa', 'aab', 'aab', 'ab', 'ab', 'aba', 'aba', 'b', 'ba', 'ba', 'baa', 'baa']
```